# Iteratively change every cell in a column of a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the value of every cell in a Pandas data frame.  Expecting `.loc` to allow me to identify a cell with the paradigm `df.loc[row_index, column_name] = cell value`, I've used the following loop:

```
table["field"] = 6 #placehodler value used only to create the column
for field, index in enumerate(table["field"]):   table.loc[index,
"field"] = table.loc[index, "field_x"] if math.isnan(table.loc[index,
"field_y"]) else table.loc[index, "field_y"]
```

However, I'm getting the following error: `KeyError: 'the label [6] is not in the [index]'`.  What is the correct syntax for selecting values by index?

Comment: Your ordering is incorrect, it should be `for index, field in enumerate(table["field"]):` but this will only work if your index is integer and monotonic, it would be safer to use `iloc` in this case

Comment: @EdChum I tried your ordering and still got the same error.  Using `.iloc` with your suggested ordering give this error: `ValueError: Location based indexing can only have [integer, integer slice (START point is INCLUDED, END point is EXCLUDED), listlike of integers, boolean array] types`

Comment: Really you should be using [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows) rather than using `enumerate`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `enumerate` to generate the index and column values, you should use [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html#pandas.DataFrame.iterrows).

Example usage:

```
In [6]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':np.random.randn(5)})
df

Out[6]:
   a         b
0  0 -0.579585
1  1 -0.582196
2  2 -0.367147
3  3 -0.363332
4  4  0.880826

In [9]:
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print('index: ', index)
    print('row: ', row)
```

output:

```
index:  0
row:  a    0.000000
b   -0.579585
Name: 0, dtype: float64
index:  1
row:  a    1.000000
b   -0.582196
Name: 1, dtype: float64
index:  2
row:  a    2.000000
b   -0.367147
Name: 2, dtype: float64
index:  3
row:  a    3.000000
b   -0.363332
Name: 3, dtype: float64
index:  4
row:  a    4.000000
b    0.880826
Name: 4, dtype: float64
```

This will allow you to access a specifc row using `df.loc[index]`, if you need the columns you can access using `row.index` in the above `for` loop